# Function overloading for all integer types

Tags: c++

I'd like my method to take any integer type as input (uint64_t, int, uint32_t, etc). Do I need to overload it with a separate method declaration for each of these? I'm worried about something bad happening if it receives a fixed-width integer of unexpected type.

```
string
to_string(uint64_t t)
{
  stringstream convert;
  convert << t;
  return convert.str();
}

string
to_string(uint32_t t)
{
  stringstream convert;
  convert << t;
  return convert.str();
}

string
to_string(int t)
{
  stringstream convert;
  convert << t;
  return convert.str();
}
```

(I don't want to use the C++11 to_string function)

Comment: You could make your function a template.  Also, what are your objections to not use `std::to_string`?

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand C++11, but my code doesn't currently compile on some machines (`error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`) and I don't want to impose the restriction of requiring C++11 on users.

On the other hand, maybe all compilers have C++11 and I just have to alter the Makefile? I guess I don't even really know what it is.

Comment: You probably have to add a flag to the compiler.  At least for GCC, it's `-std=c++11`.  Also note [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you have against `std::to_string()`, but you can just write a template and enable it on integral types:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value,
    std::string
>::type to_string(T t) 
{
    stringstream convert;
    convert << t;
    return convert.str();
}
```

Comment: So enable_if also requires C++11. Which I guess means I should probably just change the compilation flags. Thanks

Comment: @Colby There is also `boost::enable_if` and `boost::is_integral<T>` if C++11 is not an option.